# How to publish WebService using Endpoint.publish() method?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am making a basic Hello World Web Service with help of some tutorials online.
I made a basic Java Project(non dynamic) in Eclipse. On running the code as Java Application and visiting the URL "http://localhost:9292/ws/hello" I receive"localhost page isn't working-ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on my browser.Following is the code. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

SayHello.java

```
package com.example.hello;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class SayHello  {

@WebMethod
public String getHello(String name) {

    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

}

LaunchService.java

```
package com.example.hello;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class LaunchService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9292/ws/hello", new SayHello());

    }

}
```

Comment: Check if http://localhost:9292/ws/hello?wsdl returns you the wsdl file on the browser

Comment: yes @mhasan, it does return me the WSDL file.

Comment: Please try replacing your localhost with the IP address or with 
0.0.0.0 incase it is (IPv4) or
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0incase it is (IPv6)

Comment: @mhasan, No, it doesn't work, still able to see the wsdl though.

Answer (score 0):

@WebService and associated annotations are used for JAX-WS which are SOAP Web services. Requests to the service are made via POST so that is why your GET does not work. GET for ?WSDL is request for service descriptor.

With SOAP client it will work fine (e.g. SOAP UI)

if you want to build REST service then use JAX-RS or Restlet or something else

(2 years late to the party but I thought I might help someone :) )